# Why does substr work differently when passed directly into a method?

Tags: arrays, perl, substring, substr

I've a question about perl that I used to not bother about in the past, but it's bugging me now.

I have a method call saveItems which takes in a value from a text log and parses the input.

so I have this few lines in the method.

```
$intime  = $_[1];
$timeHr  = substr($intime, 0,2); 
$timeMin = substr($intime, 2,2);
$timeSec = substr($intime, 5,2);
$object[$_[0]]->hr($timeHr);
$object[$_[0]]->min($timeMin);
$object[$_[0]]->sec($timeSec);
```

$intime being the value of the time passed into this method.
Sample of $intime: 0431:12

My question is that why does the above not give me any error but when I try to shorten the lines like so :

```
$object[$_[0]]->hr(substr($intime, 0,2));
$object[$_[0]]->min(substr($intime, 2,2));
$object[$_[0]]->sec(substr($intime, 5,2));
```

Only the first one works while the rest gives me an out of string error.

I am relatively new to perl, as you can see, but can anyone give me an answer to this?

**EDIT**

Sample HR:

```
sub hr {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { $self->{HR} = shift }
    return $self->{HR};
}
```

**EDIT**

Case Closed.. Read my answer post

Comment: Can you tell us the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: "substr outside of string at line :  xx"..
   
where xx contains "$object[$_[0]]->min(substr($intime, 2,2)); "

Comment: What do you get if you add `.''` after each substr?

Comment: somehow, it only complains about the second line no matter how I rearrange the lines

Comment: @Eric it works! but can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matter has been resolved.

The way of using substr as follows, are able to perform normally, without errors.

```
$object[$_[0]]->hr(substr($intime, 0,2)); 
$object[$_[0]]->min(substr($intime, 2,2)); 
$object[$_[0]]->sec(substr($intime, 5,2));
```

However, it is the log file that has trailing blank lines that got this script to fail.

Thanks to @ysth for asking me to reproduce the problem, when I realized that the problem actually lies with the log file instead of the script.

Lesson learnt: Check the codes AND the source before raising an issue

Answer (score 3):

From the comments above, adding `.''` after each `substr` solved your problem. The reason for this is that the `->hr`, `->min`, and `->sec` methods are modifying their argument in some way.  Without seeing it further I can't say for certain what is happening.

The `substr` function returns a value that is a valid lvalue.  This means that it can be assigned to.  So when something in those methods assigns to the slice from substr, it is interfering with the other methods.

Appending an empty string fixes the problem by breaking the alias between the slice and the original string (stored in `$intime`).

If you wrote the `hr`, `min` and `sec` methods, you should figure out why they are modifying their arguments.  Adding `print "[$intime]\n";` statements between each method call should be revealing.

Comment: So by appending an empty string, it separates the slice from the original into some sort of a new variable on its own, thus giving us the ability to manipulate it?

Comment: it still prints [0431:12] between each method call and I've updated the question with a sample of hr method

Comment: The concatenation operator `.` copies its arguments into a new string.  During this copy the alias is broken.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the time.. I've fully understood this concept

Comment: @robobooga: the sample hr you show wouldn't have the problem described, and it printing the full 0431:12 between each method call also indicates something else was going on, at least in some of your tries.

Comment: @ysth but how isit so that only by copying the slice to another variable, will the error not occur? As you can see my whole script is just to read the time, and substr it, then subsequently print out the output of $object[i]->hr/min or sec and no other method besides the saveItems and the object calls have been used or even called

Comment: @robobooga: I don't know; something is happening in code that you aren't showing us.  I'm just saying the problem doesn't not exist in the code you *have* shown.  Note that I think Eric Strom is almost certain to have correctly identified the problem, but again the problem doesn't exist in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Can you come up with self-contained runnable code that demonstrates the problem?  The problem you describe doesn't quite match up with the code you show, though I don't understand @object's role in your code.

The following works just fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Class;

sub new { bless {} }

sub saveItems {
    my $intime = $_[1];
    $_[0]->hr(substr($intime, 0,2));
    $_[0]->min(substr($intime, 2,2));
    $_[0]->sec(substr($intime, 5,2));
}

sub hr {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { $self->{HR} = shift }
    return $self->{HR};
}

sub min {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { $self->{MIN} = shift }
    return $self->{MIN};
}

sub sec {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { $self->{SEC} = shift }
    return $self->{SEC};
}

package main;

my $object = Class->new();
$object->saveItems( '0431:12' );
print "hr: ", $object->hr(), " min: ", $object->min(), " sec: ", $object->sec(), "\n";
```